# Measuring Percentage using Pressure Stall Information (PSI)

Tags: kernel, 22.04, cpu

Can I measure the percentage using the PSI of CPU stall time? the command gives the percentage for 10, 60, and 300 sec. However, I am using the total field of it. how to calculate the percentage of the time the process is stalled in 100ms windows time.
[image: PSI-command-output]

> The total field is a lot more interesting. It represents the total time in microseconds that processes were starved for CPU. If you keep reading this file every 100 milliseconds and subtract the value of total read previously, you will get the time in microseconds for which processes were starved of CPU between your previous read and now. So, we’re talking something very high-resolution here. This is not comparable to anything previously available on Linux.